# How to use Traceroute --mtu on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, unix, traceroute

I am trying to do the following

```
Traceroute --mtu google.com
```

however I get a `usage: traceroute [-M first_ttl] etc` giving me all the command lines. How can I use --mtu with traceroute on mac?

I am also trying to use tracepath as a alternative, but keep getting the error `command not found`

I have looked everywhere for a solution but can't find one. Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--mtu` option is probably unique to the GNU/Linux traceroute, which comes from a GNU heritage rather than a BSD heritage like macOS.

You can usually install the GNU version of any well-known Unix software onto macOS using an open source software package manager, such as Homebrew.